# Why does emacs start up small?

Tags: emacs, xorg

My emacs is coming up really small, and this is how I'm launching it:

```
[jah@localhost ~]$ xrdb -query -all
Xcursor.size:   24
Xcursor.theme:  Adwaita
Xft.antialias:  1
Xft.dpi:    96
Xft.hinting:    1
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight
Xft.rgba:   rgb
[jah@localhost ~]$ emacs -q
```

[image]

What else besides X resources and `.emacs` settings could do this? This is GNOME 3 on X on CentOS 7.

Comment: Try running `Emacs -Q`. If this doesn't help, does `-mm` start it as maximized? Could you post your `.emacs` file?

Comment: `emacs -Q` exhibits the same behavior for me as `emacs -q`. `emacs -Q -mm` does, in fact, start maximized. I don't think my `.emacs` file is relevant if I'm using `-q` or `-Q`, is it? Renaming it to something else also doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: This is one weird problem. Maybe you should uninstall emacs, search and delete all emacs folders and files, then re-install.

Comment: I'm going to call this my fault. I had forgotten I was running an emacs 25 that I built. There must have been something wrong with the build.

Comment: In this case my comment above would have probably solved the problem, so I put it up as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem happens with a locally compiled version of emacs.

The solution to this uncommon behavior would be to uninstall emacs,
search and delete all emacs folders and files, then re-install from the repository.

Comment: Downvoting an accepted answer. Interesting.

Comment: Weird - it wasn't me!

Comment: I don't understand why the question got a bunch of upvotes, frankly. I wanted to delete it, but I didn't want you to lose your bounty or get in trouble for deleting a question with an answer.

Comment: I wouldn't delete. Yes, it was your doing, but it could happen to others that do the same thing.